# Why a cast is necessary in this case?

Tags: java, casting, wildcard

Let's say I have a method with the following signature:

```
public static <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> dosomething(Class<T> clazz)
```

If I tried to call this using a wildcard class, like in the example below

```
Class<?> clazz = Integer.class
Set<Class<?>> result = dosomething(clazz);
```

The compiler complains about the following:

```
Error: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible equality constraints java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?
```

So the fix for that is to add a cast in the method call.

```
Set<Class<?>> result = (Set<Class<?>>) dosomething(clazz);
```

I am wondering why is that the cast is needed in this particular case and if there is any workaround to avoid casting...
I am using java-8 for this.
Thanks

Comment: I think compiler doesn't know that Class<?> will extend T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the wildcard type parameter in `Set<Class<?>> result`, whereas your method returns `Set<Class<? extends T>>`

So, result could contain Class-Objects of any Type (subtypes of Object), the method only returns Objects that are subtypes of T (as mentioned in the compiler error).

Either this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?> clazz = Integer.class;
    Set<Class<?>> result = dosomething(clazz);
}

public static <T> Set<Class<?>> dosomething(Class<T> clazz){
    return new HashSet<Class<?>>();
}
```

or this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class;
    Set<Class<? extends Integer>> result = dosomething(clazz);
}

public static <T> Set<Class<? extends T>> dosomething(Class<T> clazz){
    return new HashSet<Class<? extends T>>();
}
```

will work without an error.

In your code, because of type erasure the compiler can't be sure your code is correct at runtime and therefore complains.